# reCAPTCHA with integrated PHP

Tags: php, recaptcha, phpmailer

I try use reCaptcha and integrated with php, so if code is correct email will sent.
So my problem here, when I type code wrong, the message show wrong code, that correct but when I type correct code their will go to successsful page also correct but I not receive any email.

*I think is maybe I put my script in wrong place (between if else).

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {

 die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");

  } else {

$full_name= $_POST["full_name"];
$email= $_POST["email"];
$address1= $_POST["address1"];
$address2= $_POST["address2"];
$postcode= $_POST["postcode"];
$city= $_POST["city"];
$state= $_POST["state"];
$country= $_POST["country"];
$telephone= $_POST["telephone"];
$month= $_POST["month"];
$birthday= $_POST["birthday"];
$birthyear= $_POST["birthyear"];

require_once('lib/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->SetFrom('ruslyrossi46@gmail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo("ruslyrossi46@gmail.com");
$address = "ruslyrossi46@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address);
$mail->Subject    = "FLOW";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->Body = "Sign Up Details<br><br> 
-------------------------------------------------------------<br>
First Name : $full_name<br>
Address : $address1<br>  
Alternate Address : $address2<br> 
Postcode : $postcode<br> 
State : $state<br> 
City : $city<br> 
Country : $country<br> 
Phone Number :  $telephone<br> 
Email : $email<br> 
Birth Of Day :  Day:$birthday  Month:$month Years:$birthyear<br> 

Thank You!<br>

------------------------------------------------------------<br>
";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Where is $mail->send() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed

```
if($mail->Send())  
{ 
    echo 'sent'; 
}  
else  
{ 
    echo 'error'; 
}
```

at the end (inside the else as last thing)

This is just an example, customize it as your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot...too many coding in my head...